# Does my Google oAuth2 Token look right?

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0

I am programming a web server to support oAuth2 for Google APIs and am following [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer).  Everything seems to be working fine up to the point where I try to make a Google API using the Access Token.  Example call from the documentation:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=1/fFBGRNJru1FQd44AzqT3Zg
```

When I try it with my access token I get **401 invalid token** error.

Looking through the literature, all examples show the Access Token in format **1/fFBGR......**. My Access Token is of form **ya29.AHES67z.......** and is much longer (see the snippet below containing response from google).

```
oauth2 request:{
"access_token" : "ya29.AHES67zeEn-RDg9CA5gGKMLKuG4uVB7W4O4WjNr-NBfY6Dtad4vbIZ",
"token_type" : "Bearer",
"expires_in" : 3600
}
```

So it appears my token is incorrect.  Do I have to encode/decode it?

Comment: please provide more details: how exactly you got the token and what are you calling.
I guess that your issue may be because the access_token is url encoded (if you received it with implicit grant flow) or should be URL Encoded.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've been recently playing around with OAuth2.0 from VBA.

```
Authorization Code Begins With: 4/Omoy    (30 Characters Long)  
Access_Token Begins With:       ya29.AHES (60 Characters Long)    
Refresh_Token Begins With:      1/Ry68    (45 Characters Long)
```

I didn't have to do any decoding or encoding to use these values. These were working, functional values.

Comment: good information! i thought i was having problems with the ya29.AHES tokens being so different and causing errors on my server, but when i read this answer, i at least knew i had the right thing. when poring over the "sign in with google+" documentation, i discovered that in little tiny small print, it mentioned that when creating an app on their API console, it is necessary to mark it as "other" and not as "iOS". when i made this change, it started working correctly.  presumably, at the point where i want to share with google+, i'll create another API console ID with iOS turned on for that …

Comment: This answer is outdated. The access token for my attempts start with ya29.a0Aa, suggesting that ya29 is the common factor. Also, my access token is 160 symbols long and I've seen 102 on other forums: it could be changing over time.

Refresh token 1/09Sy... so I would assume 1/ to be start. The string is 103 symbols long.