# How to call Gmail API using PHP and cURL?

Tags: php, curl, gmail-api

I have the oauth access token but my get request fails. Below is my code:

```
    $response = array();
    $crl = curl_init();
    $newurl = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/myemail@gmail.com/messages?access_token=" . $result['access_token'];
    echo $newurl . "</br>";
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $newurl);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $reply = curl_exec($crl);
    if ( $reply ) {
        echo 'successfully retrieved messages</br>';
        echo $reply;
    } else {
        echo 'failed to get messages</br>'; // prints
        echo $reply; // prints nothing
    }
```

I confirmed that my key is correct:
[Does my Google oAuth2 Token look right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291696/does-my-google-oauth2-token-look-right)

myemail@gmail.com is certainly the one that provided access. Since this is PHP, I cannot debug because I do not have a console (I tried to print out the reply it prints nothing).

Comment: It worked. My application type is a 'Web Application' so all I have is an id and secret. I do not have a .pem file. What is this and where do I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you do not have the certificates for ssl installed properly.

I do not recommend disabling ssl check, but you can use:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);.
```

The thing you should do is:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "path/to/cacert.pem");
```

[Download](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) ([direct](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem)) the cert and use the above code.