# How to use API Key while making an HTTP GET Request to Google Contacts REST API

Tags: rest, gmail-api

I have been trying to query the Google GMAIL API via REST.

I have done the following things already:
 1. Create a project in console.developer.google.com 
 2. Create an API Key for the Project
 3. Enabled the Gmail API in the console
 4. Now I'm trying to perform the following cURL request:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json'  https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/<email_id>/messages?key=<my_API_KEY>
```

But I get the following response

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

What Do I do?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Try going to the [Oauth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/), authorize with the Gmail API scopes, and put this access token you get in your request, and see if that works.

Comment: Nope, same error as before

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952836/how-to-call-gmail-api-using-php-and-curl

Comment: @abielita I don't think its a duplicate, the link you have mentioned refers to client side auth using Public Key, I am asking via API Key. Also, I am able to connect to Google Calendar using API Key but I am unable to do the same thing to Gmail

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a lot of head scratching, I came across this: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/api-keys

This link states that API Keys only allow you to access **Public Data** The request I was trying to make was **Private Data**

So, it mandatory that I use OAuth2.0 to authenticate the user and then use the access token in the url.

Once the user has granted my app access via OAuth2.0, I have to pass the access_token

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json'  https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/<email_id>/messages?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

I used https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib libraryto handle OAuth2.0 and get the token, then made CURL requests using PHP.

Hope it helps :)