# Gmail API curl in PHP gives 404 (with fresh token)

Tags: php, api, curl, gmail, gmail-api

I try to connect to my gmail from a PHP page over the gmail API. I will browse to my PHP page to an embedded system to easily receive and send emails.
At the moment i received my token using OAuth (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web). But it doesn't work to receive the mail list, I end up with a google 404 page when i visit my PHP page.
Image of the 404 error on my PHP page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuuVQ.jpg
PHP Code:

```
$apikey = "APIKEY";
$token = "received over OAuth in console";

$q   = array("q"=>"PHP HTTP request");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/EMAIL@gmail.com/messages?includeSpamTrash=true&maxResults=5&key=APIKEY");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$q);  //Post Fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$headers = [
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Content-Length: ".strlen("PHP HTTP request"),
    "User-Agent: PHP Test",
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Authorization: Bearer ".base64_encode($token),
    "Cookie: key=".base64_encode($apikey),

    "Host: www.XXXXXXXX.be",
    "Referer: http://www.XXXXXXXX.be/test/test.php" //Your referrer address
];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
print  $server_output ;
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25952917/11581830) it could guide you down the right path.

Comment: @AMolina thx but that didn't help me. It did give me motivation and I have found another website with working code! Thank you

Comment: Glad your issue is solved!

Answer (score 1):

I have found this website: https://wp-time.com/send-email-via-gmail-api-using-php/
With this it is already possible to send. I am working to import the inbox to view received mails as well and it is working! I also made it doing the sign-in by itself by adding following headers and $mail the gmail and $password the password in plain text. You can mail me if you need help/php-code. When I am done my code should be translated in an API to easily send and receive emails.

```
'username' => $mail,
'password' => $password,
'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
```

Comment: I never got to making the API but the initial project worked to send and see emails.