# Retrieve Google Access Token after authenticated using Firebase Authentication

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am trying to retrieve Google Access Token to access Google REST API such as [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) from an authenticated user (using Firebase Authentication).

I have successfully integrated Google Sign-In in my app with the help of [Firebase-UI for Android - Auth](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth) library. The token retrieved from `FirebaseUser.getToken()` method is not a valid Google Access Token for REST API.

```
user.getToken(true).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            String token = task.getResult().getToken();
            // 'token' is not a Google Access Token
        }
    }
});
```

In [Google Sign-In for Web guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#redirect-mode), it's possible to get the access token by calling `var token = result.credential.accessToken;`, but I can't find the similar method in Android.

Any inputs? Please comment here if I do not provide enough information. Thank you :)

Comment: Have you enabled API from console

Comment: which console @KrunalKapadiya ? I have enabled Google in Firebase Authentication Console

Comment: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard?project=YOUR_PROJECT_ID, Enable YouTube Data API v3

Comment: For more details you can visit this link https://github.com/Krunalkapadiya/Youtube-Player-Android

Comment: @KrunalKapadiya yes, I have enabled and used `YouTube Data API v3` for some methods that can run without Access Token but only the API key. For more information, I am trying to get channels managed by authorized user and I think `YouTube Android Player API` don't have that method (correct me if I'm wrong), that's why I need to access the REST API to get that data.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The way you are doing will give you firebase id token, see [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#getToken(boolean)).

---

There are three types of tokens you will come across in firebase :

- **Firebase ID tokens**

  Created by Firebase when a user signs in to a Firebase app. These tokens are signed JWTs that securely identify a user in a Firebase project. These tokens contain basic profile information for a user, including the user's ID string, which is unique to the Firebase project. Because the integrity of ID tokens can be verified, you can send them to a backend server to identify the currently signed-in user.
- **Identity Provider tokens**

  Created by federated identity providers, such as Google and Facebook. These tokens can have different formats, but are often OAuth 2.0 access tokens. Firebase apps use these tokens to verify that users have successfully authenticated with the identity provider, and then convert them into credentials usable by Firebase services.
- **Firebase Custom tokens**

  Created by your custom auth system to allow users to sign in to a Firebase app using your auth system. Custom tokens are JWTs signed using a service account's private key. Firebase apps use these tokens much like they use the tokens returned from federated identity providers.

---

Now, what you are getting is firebase Id token, what you need is Identity Provider Token.

Its simple to get Identity Provider token, its just one step previous to the step you have shown.

So, the way we sign in google using firebase is mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin).

I will add below the complete code which displays a button in UI, which on clicked, will sign in user to google account. And then I will get the google access token, which is then send to firebase, where it is converted to firebase token Id.

I presume that you have configured android app for google sign in, if not, you can go into details [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating).

---

**(To cut things short, just look at Step 5 below, if you have done setup already.)**

---

**Code** :

1. **Configure Google SignIn and GoogleApiClient** :

   ```
    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
       .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
       .requestEmail()
       .build();

    // NOTE : 
    // The string passed to requestIdToken, default_web_client_id, 
    // can be obtained from credentials page (https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials).
    // There mentioned Web application type client ID is this string.


    // ... 
    // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
    // options specified by gso.
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
       .enableAutoManage(this /* Activity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
       .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
       .build();
   ```
2. **Add the Google Sign-In button to your app**

   ```
   <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
       android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   ```
3. **Set SignIn Click Listener**

   ```
   findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v){
           Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
           startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);   
       }
   });
   ```
4. **Override `OnActivityResult` method in Activity** :

   ```
   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
       if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
           // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
           GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
           firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account); // This method is implemented in step 5.
       } else {
           // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
           // ...
       }
   }
   ```
5. **Firebase Authentication With Google SignInAccount**

   ```
   String idTokenString = "";
   ...
   private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
       Log.d(TAG, "Google User Id :" + acct.getId());

       // --------------------------------- //
       // BELOW LINE GIVES YOU JSON WEB TOKEN, (USED TO GET ACCESS TOKEN) : 
       Log.d(TAG, "Google JWT : " + acct.getIdToken());
       // --------------------------------- //

       // Save this JWT in global String : 
       idTokenString = acct.getIdToken();

       AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
       mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
           .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
               @Override
               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                   if(task.isSuccessful()){
                       // --------------------------------- //
                       // BELOW LINE GIVES YOU FIREBASE TOKEN ID : 
                       Log.d(TAG, "Firebase User Access Token : " + task.getResult().getToken());
                       // --------------------------------- //
                   }
                   // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                   // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                   // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                   else {
                       Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                       Toast.makeText(GoogleSignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               }
           });
   }
   ```
6. **Final Step : Auth Listeners for Firebase**

   ```
   private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
   private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // ...
       mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
       mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
           @Override
           public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
               FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
               if (user != null) {
                   // User is signed in
                   Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
               } else {
                  // User is signed out
                  Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
               }
               // ...
           }
      };
      // ...
   }

   //...

   @Override
   public void onStart() {
       super.onStart();
       mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
   }

   @Override
   public void onStop() {
       super.onStop();
       if (mAuthListener != null) {
           mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
       }
   }
   ```

---

So, your answer lies in Step 5, which was just before you authenticated to firebase and just after you authenticated in google sign in.

Hope it helps !

---

**UPDATE :**

**Its important that in Step 1, you request for token Id, otherwise in Step 5, you will get null token id. For more see [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount.html#getIdToken()). I have updated Step 1.**

---

**UPDATE :**

**As per discussion, the retrieved token was JWT token as written [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount.html#getIdToken()). And what we need is google access token. Below code uses the JWT token to fire at OAuth backend and retrieve this access token :**

(Note : I have used okhttp version 2.6.0, other versions might have different methods)

**Code :**

```
...
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
RequestBody requestBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
            .add("grant_type", "authorization_code")
            .add("client_id", "<Your-client-id>")   // something like : ...apps.googleusercontent.com
            .add("client_secret", "{Your-client-secret}")
            .add("redirect_uri","")
            .add("code", "4/4-GMMhmHCXhWEzkobqIHGG_EnNYYsAkukHspeYUk9E8") // device code.
            .add("id_token", idTokenString) // This is what we received in Step 5, the jwt token.
            .build();

final Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token")
        .post(requestBody)
        .build();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(final Request request, final IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());                
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
            final String message = jsonObject.toString(5);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, message);                    
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

---

Here is the output which has access token as required :

```
I/onResponse: {
          "expires_in": 3600,
          "token_type": "Bearer",
          "refresh_token": "1\/xz1eb0XU3....nxoALEVQ",
          "id_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjQxMWY1Ym......yWVsUA",
          "access_token": "ya29.bQKKYah-........_tkt980_qAGIo9yeWEG4"
     }
```

Hope now it helps !

Comment: Thank you for your amazing answer, but `acct.getIdToken()` is not a Google Access Token, Based on [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10299106/5292961), Google Access Token begins with `ya29.AHES...` and only 60 chars long (`acct.getIdToken()` returns 1088 chars).
Again, thank you for your answer! At least now I just need to know how to get `access token` from `id token`. After quick research, looks like I have to deploy a backend to retrieve the access token. [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998335/how-to-get-access-token-after-user-is-signed-in-from-gmail-in-android)

Comment: Okay, I think I got it wrong here, the token that you will get here is a JWT(Json Web Token). If you don't know the difference between JWT and OAuth token, please google it. What you are talking about 60 char long is OAuth access token. So, what you need to do is use this jwt token to hit `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token`, now this you can do at client side itself no need for server side. I will update my code for fetching oauth access token from android itself. Thanks for pointing it out, will update as early as possible.

Comment: The code you just updated comes from the link in my previous comment. I have tried that and I get this response `{ "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad Request" }`. Should I put the same value for `code` as in your answer or where can I get that `device code`? From [this guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp), looks like the value for `code` is the response from authorization request. Now I'm confused. haha

Comment: Well then the problem is that the account holder has not given permissions to you to use it. Remember that google page which asks you : "Allow app to access basic info from this account", this must be granted by user to get this access token. For doing that, in detail you can look here : `https://github.com/lightlz/google-oauth-2/blob/master/devices.md#获取用户码` (need to translate this page to english). You will get device code by firing request to : `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code`, mentioned in link.

Comment: Just in case you need to know, these days there are client libraries to handle all such oauth authentication stuff, we don't need to worry by access tokens and all underlying stuff. So, for example, you want to access youtube data api after login, just follow here : `https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/ytdl/MainActivity.java`. Its simple and doesn't dive into access token stuff.

Comment: Ah, I think I might just try the client libraries to handle this auth stuff. Thank you for all the links :)

Comment: @Wilik since you mentioned [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998335/how-to-get-access-token-after-user-is-signed-in-from-gmail-in-android), for your question `where can I get that device code?` in your comment above, that is `String authCode = acct.getServerAuthCode();`

Comment: @Wilik please read [this doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp)

Comment: Currently, I implemented a deprecated method to get access token from [this guide](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth#SpecifyingScopes), I just need to pass the authenticated user's email to `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()` it's deprecated (I don't know why) but at least it works :) Thank you @BNK for your answer, I will try that method again and get back to you. :D

Comment: @Wilik I think using "GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()" is right too. I cannot find the info about its deprecation.

Comment: @Wilik about `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()`, I think you can also read [this blogspot](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/05/improving-security-and-user-experience.html) from [Isabella Chen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5827947/isabella-chen)

Comment: How it is possible in Web ?

Answer (score 31):

Try [GoogleAuthUtil.getToken](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html#getToken(android.content.Context,%20android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) where [scope](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/Scopes) is like "oauth2:scope1 scope2 scope3"

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
}

private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            final GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();

                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            String scope = "oauth2:"+Scopes.EMAIL+" "+ Scopes.PROFILE;
                            String accessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), account.getAccount(), scope, new Bundle());
                            Log.d(TAG, "accessToken:"+accessToken); //accessToken:ya29.Gl...

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                AsyncTask.execute(runnable);

        } else {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch dude :)

Comment: Thanks buddy saved ma day

Comment: Wish I had more upvotes to give. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Saved my day too! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I'm following the @vovkas solution, and want to let you know that with the last update `11.6.0` you can get the `Account` needed more easily, so you can have everything inside a *handy dandy* `AsyncTask` to be reused whenever you want to:

```
public class GetToken extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private final Context context;

    public GetToken(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            String scope = "oauth2:" + Scopes.EMAIL + " " + Scopes.PROFILE;
            GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context);
            return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, account.getAccount(), scope, new Bundle());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The key is to use `GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context)`.