# How to Approach Google Sign-In With Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, google-api, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I want to incorporate Google sign-in in my app (**not with the Firebase UI as seen** [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth)), but manually so to speak, as seen [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin?authuser=0)

**In the image I provided below there's a part that says:**

> You must pass your server's client ID to the requestIdToken method. To
>   find the OAuth 2.0 client ID:
>
> a. Open the Credentials page in the API Console.
>
> b. The Web application type client ID is your backend server's OAuth
>   2.0 client ID.

I did some research and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40838154/retrieve-google-access-token-after-authenticated-using-firebase-authentication) which was very informative but the clarification I am seeking wasn't quite there.

**What I wanted to know is:**

If I am **only using Firebase** as my backend and **no physical server of my own** do I need to do the step that says

> You must pass your server's client ID to the requestIdToken method...

Or am I fine with just leaving this line of code:
`.requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))` 
since I am only using Firebase and no physical servers of my own?

I just need some clarification before I continue with implementing Google sign-in this way and not with the FirebaseUI.

[image: Firebase Google Sign-In Authentication]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [FirebaseUI 0.3](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/a934f3b7e3ef51158efaf52c1ef7359811ba5064/library/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/google/GoogleAuthProvider.java#L73), the following lines were needed to build the Google sign-in options:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestIdToken(googleClientId)
    .requestEmail()
    .build();
```

In which `googleClientId` is the user Id as described in the [Firebase official documentation for Google authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/google.html). The most important thing to note here is that you need to create a web `application`, despite the fact that you're building an Android app.

But, once FirebaseUI 0.3.1 was released, we see that we don't need to specify an id token anymore. The following lines of code, are all you need:

```
GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
    .requestEmail()
    .build();
```

Less configuration to worry about.

Comment: Ok, but I'm not using FirebaseUI I'm using their guidelines to implement Google sign-in manually using Firebase SDK on their official website, not the FirebaseUI on gitHub. So if I'm doing it via their official website am I good to go with just using the default web client id string?

Comment: Go with the official doc. Yes, that's correct, use only the `R.string.default_web_client_id`.