# Firebase IDToken to Google OAuth2 access token in Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-oauth, google-authentication

We use Firebase Auth in our Unity game and [Google SignIn](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity) and need to access Google services like Google Classroom.

Firebase Auth gives us a JWT IdToken after signing in using this code https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#unity

```
Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task2.Result;
var token = await newUser.TokenAsync(false);
```

I tried passing this token to Google Classroom service but it requires an OAuth2 AccessToken.

How I convert this JWT Firebase IdToken to an AccessToken that can be used by the GoogleClassroom API?

I am looking for the AccessToken to pass to the Google Classroom APIs

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromAccessToken(AccessToken);
var service = new ClassroomService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });
```

I have tried the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40838154/retrieve-google-access-token-after-authenticated-using-firebase-authentication) to this question but the service is returning 404.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to get google access token..!
You can simply get it by a simple API call.

```
IEnumerator GetAccessToken()
        {
            WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
            form.AddField("client_id", "your_webClientId");
            form.AddField("client_secret", "your_clientsecret");
            form.AddField("grant_type", "authorization_code");
            form.AddField("code", "your_authcode);
            UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token", form);
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
            {
            }
            else
            {

                //Access token response
                GoogleData googleData =JsonUtility.FromJson<GoogleData>(www.downloadHandler.text); 
                Debug.LogError(googleData.access_token);
                
            }
        }
```

In the API success you can parse the response in to data model class.
NOTE:Do not chane "grant_type" field value.

```
[System.Serializable]
    public class GoogleData
    {
        public string access_token;
        public string token_type;
        public int expires_in;
        public string refresh_token;
    }
```