# Using the google-auth-library-java to get a new access token from client secret and refresh token

Tags: java, google-api-client, google-oauth-java-client

Currently, I am using the following code snippet to use as a credential for accessing the Gmail API on Java / Kotlin.

```
val credentials = GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setClientSecrets(clientSecrets)
                    .setJsonFactory(GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance())
                    .setTransport(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport())
                    .build()
                    .apply {
                        this.refreshToken = refreshToken
                        refreshToken()
                    }
```

This is currently working, however, the `GoogleCredential` class is deprecated. Is there a non-deprecated version of accomplishing the same thing? I have tried to find the equivalent but having no luck looking through Google API docs so far.

I have access to the client secrets (in a downloaded .json file) and the `refreshToken` retrieved on the last authorization flow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40946219/10954249 I think this will help you